# typo3 - tx_news and image display

Tags: typo3

I would like to have the pictures displayed in the frontend, even if in the backend the checkmark "Relation" ---> "Show in preview views" is not set.

In the template, if you set the hook, it comes through "news_image_intS". But not when the catch is out. Is there another variable for this or do you have to program another extension for it?

Extension "news" v3.2.8

typo3 v6.2.31

Answer (score 0):

"news_image_intS".is maybe for solr but not the name in fluid templates of the extension